# Microdata tags for Facebook catalogues

Tags: facebook-opengraph, facebook-pixel

I am trying to setup FB Catalogue using the FB pixel. When I try to select my pixel (already installed on the website), the error I get states

> To use this pixel, you need to install required microdata tags on your website

[On the FB documentation](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1175004275966513) the suggestion is to use the protocols OpenGraph or Schema.org.

Here are the required tags for OpenGraph:

> og:title: The title of the item.
>   og:description: A description of the item.
>   og:url: The complete URL for the product page.
>   og:image: A link to the image used on the product page.
>   product:brand: The brand name of the item.
>   product:availability: The current availability of the item. You can choose "in stock", "out of stock", "preorder", "available for order" or "discontinued".
>   product:condition: The current condition of the item. You can choose "new", "refurbished" or "used".
>   product:price:amount: The current price of the item. The current price of the item. Don't include symbols like "£" in the price.
>   product:price:currency: The currency for the price. The currency for the price, in ISO format (for example, GBP).
>   product:retailer_item_id: The retailer's ID for the item.
>
> Example
>
> ```html
> <header>
>
> ...
>
> <!-- Open Graph Metadata -->
>
> <meta property="og:title" content="Facebook T-Shirt">
>
> <meta property="og:description" content="Unisex Facebook T-shirt, Small">
>
> <meta property="og:url" content="https://example.org/facebook">
>
> <meta property="og:image" content="https://example.org/facebook.jpg">
>
> <meta property="product:brand" content="Facebook">
>
> <meta property="product:availability" content="in stock">
>
> <meta property="product:condition" content="new">
>
> <meta property="product:price:amount" content="9.99">
>
> <meta property="product:price:currency" content="USD">
>
> <meta property="product:retailer_item_id" content="facebook_tshirt_001">
>
> <!-- End Open Graph Metadata -->
>
> ...
>
> </header>
> ```

What I don't understand is if I have to manually add this information to each and every product I have on the website?

How do I setup this?

Answer (score 0):

### I got this result just by adding product_type to the above microdata tags.

[missing facebook microdata tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGyPB.png)

Example: Home & Garden > Kitchen & Dining > Appliances > Refrigerators

Answer (score -1):

Yes you have to include all those necessary metadata tags to each page dynamically or if you have less than 50 pages then you can go with static implementation for each page, But it will be good to insert all these necessary metadata dynamically. OR you can include those into your product catalog feed sheet.

To add the microdata, you can use 2 different communication systems: OpenGraph or Schema.org. You can visit the Facebook for Developers website to learn how to set microdata tags for catalogs. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/product-catalog/update-options#microdata-tags